# OptaPlanner HardMediumSoftBigDecimalScore isn´t recognized like score type

Tags: spring-boot, drools, optaplanner

I´m using OptaPlanner to solve optimization problems, I´m working with HardMediumSoftBigDecimalScore and OptaPlanner said me:

**field private org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buid
in.hardmediumsoftbigdecimal.HardMediumSoftBigDecimalScore asota.lubricantselection.lsopt.domain.bearinglubricantsolution.BearingLubricantSolution.score) that returns a scoreType (class org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardmediumsoftbigdecimal.HardMediumSoftBigDecimalScore) that is not recognized
as a default Score implementation.
If you intend to use a custom implementation, maybe set a scoreDefinition in the PlanningScore annotation.**

I tried with 7.43.1 version and 7.40.0 version the same error persist.
Thank you in advance, I look forward to your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I remember fixing this bug for master the other day. It was simply not hooked in.
The fix will be part of the `8.0.0.Beta1` release. The fix is not backported to 7.x at this point (if a customer submits a support ticket, we will prioritize the backport).

Workaround wise, there's nothing I can immediately think about... sorry.